# Why the private IP is not released when an instance is stopped?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have create an AWS EC2 instance and, I have stopped the instance for some reasons. When I start the instance back, I happen to notice that the public IP address have changed but, the private IP address remains unchanged.

I assume that the public IPs address will be released from the instance and move to the public IP pool since it is dynamic IP address unless we attach an Elastic IP address.

May I ask why the private IP address remains unchanged and what is the reason/purpose behind that?

I have tried googling but couldn't find the exact answer. I appreciate your input and help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a function of how AWS VPCs work. From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html):

> A private IP address remains associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and restarted, and is released when the instance is terminated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that Amazon has designed the EC2 flow in such a way that the private IPs will not be released when an instance is stopped but, I would like to know the technical reason behind that. Is it because we would need the private IP address to get in touch with the instance in case of instance down or any other possible technical reason/login behind this? I would really appreciate your kind input on this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You usually connect multiple instances between each other. you reference the IP of one instance in others configuration files.
You don't want to re-edit all your configuration when the instance is stop/started.
that's why it is by design